# Proxy or FiddlerCore

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, http-proxy, fiddlercore

I'm trying to write a program that catches the HTTP get requests.
I have found Fiddler-core a genius library that should do exactly what I want.

The thing is, I'm trying to execute a big piece code-work inside the **void FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest(Session oSession)** and it seems to block all the request and damage my surfing speed a great deal.

I have tried to use threads/tasks with no avail. 
What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
public event RequestCapture RequestCaptured;
private CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

//...stat public function:
public void RunWatch() {
   Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest;
   Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(0, FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default);
}

void FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest(Session oSession)
{
   if (RequestCaptured != null)
   {
      CancellationToken ct = cancelTokenSource.Token;
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>RequestCaptured(oSession.fullUrl), ct);
      //Handle the event in a new thread, so the Listener will continue to listen
   }

}

//close public function:
public void Close() {
   try
   {
      FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
      cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
   }
   catch { }
}
```

now i have i different class that do that:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        Listiner = new HttpWatcher.Listner();
        Listiner.RequestCaptured += RequestCaptured;

        Listiner.RunWatch();
    }

    void RequestCaptured(string url)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
```

**edit**
The question is: Is there a better way using fiddler-core? or am i to build a simple proxy for that? using something else? Thanks!

**edit2**
I have edited the code, so it would fill the missing parts.

Comment: What is RequestCaptured?

Comment: Sorry, its an event that do lots of work :), Ill post the extra code in 30 min. sorry

Comment: What kind of work? Does the work need to complete before the request can proceed? If not, just place the event data in a queue and return from the handler... Then process the queue with a different thread.

Comment: @spender that's exactly what he posted.

Comment: @PeterRitchie No, not exactly... if the event handlers are running in the ThreadPool, then there's going to be additional pressure on the ThreadPool, and it will have to spin up new threads to deal with the additional workload (e.g. the work queue is getting too long). The ThreadPool only spins up additional threads slowly and is generally optimised for small workloads. Enqueueing lots of large workloads causes a lot of latency. I'm talking about a dedicated thread for dequeueing and processing the queue, away from the ThreadPool.

Comment: @spender well, that's quite a bit different than what you first posted.  But, yes, if the FiddlerCore events are being fired on a threadpool thread *and* the event handler is also stressing the threadpool, then there will be contention there.

Comment: @spender no, it does not need to complete. That why i have tried to put it in tasks. I did not exactly got what u mean. Can you please post your answer in code so I would be able to check it and approve it? :)

Comment: @Ran I would put the data/action in *before_request* to a queue( such as [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)) and process them in a single separate thread/task.

Comment: @L.B, Do you mean a global BlockingCollection variable and handle it in a different thread?

Comment: @L.B, thanks. It works much better now. It still a bit of a slowish though. By I would apprive your answear if i could ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear here, FiddlerCore processes each Session on a threadpool thread. If you need blocking behavior, there's no need to spin up an additional thread or anything like that. If you don't need to process things in a blocking manner, then feel free to queue the data on a background queue and use tasks or another asynchronous mechanism to perform processing.

You should explain exactly what you mean when you say `damage my surfing speed a great deal`, and whether or not you see different behavior when using Fiddler rather than your application.

Comment: Thanks guru Eric, my problem is that when I add this line System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); the internet stop for 10 seconds. When I comment that line out. The internet start to work almost as normal

Comment: But @L.B got it right. the BlockingCollection works as required

Comment: @Ran: There's absolutely no reasonable explanation for that unless you have some synchronization bug somewhere in your code. Sessions are processed on background threads.

Comment: It is extremely weird then. I have tried to keep my code as thin as possible so almost all of my code is posted. Have you tested my code and it worked for you? p.s. for some another weird reason i cannot 'at' your name with the '@' char